# Is this "game of words" understandable for the native speakers?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, jokes

I wonder if the following game of words is clear to native English speakers, or does it sound confusing and weird?

I'm working on a project, dedicated to some anniversary, and related to the space thematics. I was thinking about the title which will appear as "**Anniversary**" - and then turn into "**Universary**" (in association with universe).

Is the association "readable"?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be understandable if used in the right sentence—but still possibly awkward.

Your best bet would be to put the invented word in quotes, in order to indicate that it's intentional rather than a typo.

For example:

> This is the third "universary" of the star's discovery.

It's clever, and some people might chuckle, but others could find it annoying. It would depend on the audience and its broader context.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I think it would not be clear. But it depends on the context. If you use *both* words "universe" and "anniversary" in the project, very prominently, before you use "universary", then it might be understood.

Without that context, if I saw the word "universary", I would probably think of it as a misspelled version of "university".